# Triangle of asterisks in php

Tags: php

I am having problems creating a triangle in php. This is my code.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        echo " $char &nbsp";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

The result is this.

```
*  
*   *  
*   *   *  
*   *   *   *  
*   *   *   *   *
```

But what I'm trying to do is this.

```
                *  
            *   *  
        *   *   *  
    *   *   *   *  
*   *   *   *   *
```

What should I change with my codes?

Comment: What is the value of $input?

Comment: $input is the inputted value from the textbox.

Comment: Beside my answer bellow you can use CSS style to align the text to the right 'text-align: right;' to your html block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure space is printed the correct number of times.

So first we will loop through all the white spaces, from 1 to $input - $i. here we will print the white space. Then we will loop through the astricks the number of $i times.

**Note:** we are using &nbsp two times for alignment purpose with astrick

**Here is the code**:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    for($j = 1; $j <= $input - $i; $j++) {
        echo " &nbsp&nbsp";
    }
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        echo " $char";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a native PHP function [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) where you can say how to pad the string in one of directions: `STR_PAD_RIGHT`,  `STR_PAD_BOTH` , `STR_PAD_LEFT`

```
<?php
$char = '*'; // the character to print
$input = 10; // number of rows
$padding = STR_PAD_BOTH; // STR_PAD_RIGHT,  STR_PAD_BOTH , STR_PAD_LEFT

for($i = 0; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    $stars = '';
    for($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        $stars .= " $char";
    }
    echo PHP_EOL . str_pad($stars, $input*2, ' ', $padding);
}
```

See it live: **https://eval.in/927835**

Here was used `STR_PAD_BOTH`:

```
          *         
         * *        
        * * *       
       * * * *      
      * * * * *     
     * * * * * *    
    * * * * * * *   
   * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

And here `STR_PAD_LEFT`:

```
                   *
                 * *
               * * *
             * * * *
           * * * * *
         * * * * * *
       * * * * * * *
     * * * * * * * *
   * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your main character string and "padding" string separately, then echo the concatenated result:

```
for( $i=0; $i<$input; $i++ ){

    // number of asterisks we need for this iteration
    $chars='';
    for( $j=0; $j<=$i; $j++ ){
        $chars.="$char &nbsp;";
    }

    // add spaces for alignment
    $padding='';
    for( $j=$i; $j<$input; $j++ ){
        $padding.="&nbsp; &nbsp;";
    }

    // output "padding" first, then our asterisks string
    echo $padding.$chars."<br />";

}
```